# How to upgrade to Magento 2.0 from 1.x

Tags: magento2, migration

I was going to upgrade Magento 1.7 site to Magento 2.0.

But Magento 2.0 has different structure.

Is there a way or tool to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Lastest Magento 2.x version(2.0.1) ,Add tool  [Code Migration Toolkit](https://github.com/magento/code-migration) by which ***you can transfer your 3rd party extension  of 1.x  version to 2.x structure***.

- You can Migrate *`Magento 1.x module structure`* to *`Magento 2.0`* structure
  using   Magento client Cli tool ***`bin/migrate.php migrateModuleStructure`***
- *Migrate Magento 1.x layout.xml Magento 2.0 structure file structure.
  (bin/migrate.php convertLayout*

See the full steps of migration at [Code Migration page](https://github.com/magento/code-migration)

So,before migration,**`you should have strong knowledge of Magento 2.X  structure`** Thus you can convert 1.x code to 2.x.You can understand those thing from [code-migration process](https://github.com/magento/code-migration)

But honesty ,you need  to do  lot of works for this achieve .

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 is not backwards compatible. There exist migration tools, but the general advice has been to treat a 1.x – 2.x upgrade as a re-platform.

### Tools

- [Data migration](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool-ce): Use this to migrate your data (customers, etc). See the [user guide for this tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html), also.
- [Code migration](https://github.com/magento/code-migration): This will get you some way towards converting your code to Magento 2. Note that you will still need to manually convert a lot of code to get something good. Migration of this magnitude is still a manual process, and you might be better off with a full rewrite of some areas, anyway.